# Send instant message in Skype using HTML link

Tags: html, skype

Is there anyway so you can make a link, that when you click it, you instantly send a message to a user in skype? Like I've seen:

```
<a href="skype:SKYPENAME?call">Call me</a>
```

and:

```
<a href="skype:SKYPENAME?chat">Start chat with me</a>
```

is there anyway to make a link that sends a chat message, not only starting a chat conversation?

From here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745878, it says the following: "**Sending instant messages to an individual** or establishing a group multi-chat.", but **how**?

Answer (score 2):

You can open a Group chat in following way:

```
skype:user1;user2;user3?chat&topic=Topic
```

but you can only let the API write a Message as Software.
I think it was just a Typo, because a link can't do this...

Comment: Yes the answer is no. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

### Use the Skype Web Link

- Open Skype
- Click Profile Image
- Click on "Share Profile"
- Send to anyone

Answer (score 0):

### Create your own start Call or Chat button

You can create your personalized button with the Official Skype button generator (action, color and size):

https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-contactme-buttons/